# How to make HTML generation code more efficient

Tags: html, node.js, performance, npm, code-generation

I made a Node.js package that generates HTML code from the server side. I was wondering if there's any way to increase the performance and efficiency of the code. Currently, I am writing to a file using an `async` function.

You can find the code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-generator-npm).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of elsewhere

Comment: Also if complete with code, the question is a better match at codereview